# How to manipulate a plot of partial derivatives of self-defined bivariate functions?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I have a piecewise linear function (spline) describing a progressive income tax schedule, with higher marginal rates kicking in for higher and higher incomes.

I want to understand the implications of a rule that some tax exempt income might still raise your average rate on the taxable part. Basically, with `x` being taxable income and `y` being exempt income, your taxes will be `f(x+y)/(x+y)*x`, where `f` is the nonlinear scheme that would apply to income without exemptions. I can define `f` as a piecewise linear function, see above.

To calculate marginal tax rates on taxable and exempt income, I’d simply need the partial derivates of this expression, with the particular function `f` plugged in, and this I can plot against the two variables. Or plot against one and use the other as a parameter for `Manipulate`.

The derivative looks OK in Mathematica, though it is a bit hard to check with so many cases.

However, I get empty plots, which of course are pointless to manipulate. Where does this go wrong?

```
Manipulate[Plot[D[Tax[x+y]/(x+y)*x,y],{y,0,200000}],{x,0,200000}]
```

Think of `Tax` this way:

```
Tax [z_]:= Piecewise[{
                        {0,0    <=z< 11265},
                        {0+ 0.0856(z-11265),11265<=z}
                    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) in the first argument of `Plot`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@D[Tax[x + y]/(x + y)*x, y], {y, 0, 200000}],
   {x, 0, 200000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you? I still get an empty plot, even if I move x around.

Comment: @László, it works in both version 12 (Wolfram Cloud) and version 9 (Windows 19). I posted a picture. (Perrhaps using `ClearAll[Tax]`  before you define `Tax` may help to avoid possible previous assignments getting in the way).

Comment: Great, it did the trick, thanks!